# skip pulling new changes of certain file to server from github

Tags: git, github, gitignore

My project source code is stored in GitHub and pulled to the server to run the project. There is a file which new changes should not be pulled to the `server1`. But that file is not untracked file to ignore using `.gitignore` file. Actually, new changes of the file are required to run the project on other servers.

Is there any way to skip pulling new changes of the file to `server1` using `git`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067439/exclude-specific-files-from-git-pull

Answer (score 1):

I usually keep a separate branch (locally on `server1`) that has the version of the file that I want to keep.

Whenever I fetch/pull from the remote repository, I'll specifically do a

`git checkout <mylocalbranch> - <filename>`

This will overwrite the file with your special version.

I do this same thing in situations when files have 'passwords' or server/application specifics that shouldn't be uploaded to the public repos.