# Avoid fetching updates for few version files in git pull

Tags: github

I've few version files in git repo which gets updated each build but I don't need those version changes in my local.
Doing git pull updates all the files along the version files also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067439/exclude-specific-files-from-git-pull

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. Out of two answers I think `git update-index --assume-unchanged` wont work as it'll update the file when I do `pull` or `checkout`. Another answer looks good `git fetch` and `git merge` specific files, I'll check this one. I want something which can be done in few seconds.

Comment: My general advice is to avoid situations which have files for which it is not logically clear whether they should be versioned by Git or not.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Both the solutions didn't worked for me. Even after doing `git fetch` and `git merge`. Git should be versioning those files as those files (versions) will be updated by environment build. My only requirement is to keep a different version in my local. So trying not to update the version files when I take `git pull`.