# Ignoring changes to a specific file when doing git pull

Tags: git

There's a file in my project that I'd like to change locally without it being overwritten every time I pull from the repo, i.e. I want to reject incoming changes to that specific file. My solution so far has been to do `git stash --> git pull --> git stash pop`

The file is in `.gitignore` both locally and in the repo. I've tried
`git update-index --assume-unchanged` and `git update-index --skip-worktree`, but to no avail. I was thinking of doing `git rm --chached`, but from what I've read it seems like this will delete the file from the repo, which is not what I want.

Comment: This thread may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067439/exclude-specific-files-from-git-pull

Comment: Why are these "files" in your repo at all? *this will delete the file from the repo, which is not what I want.* so what do you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude specific files from 'git pull'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067439/exclude-specific-files-from-git-pull)

Comment: @Liam I want my local version to be different from the one in the repo. I do not want to delete/edit the repo version, and I do not want the repo version to overwrite my local version when I pull.

Comment: I already tried what was mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18067439/exclude-specific-files-from-git-pull

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> The file is in `.gitignore` both locally and in the repo ...

As you have seen, this does no good if the file is actually committed.  That's because `.gitignore` does not mean *ignore this file*, it really means *shut up about this file **if** it's untracked*.  If it's *not* untracked (if it is tracked), listing the file has *no effect at all*.

> I've tried `git update-index --assume-unchanged` and `git update-index --skip-worktree`, but to no avail.

For confirmation, it would be helpful if you showed exactly where this goes wrong.  For now, I'm assuming that where it goes wrong is that those commands appear to work—they do not complain at all—but a later `git fetch && git merge` complains that it would overwrite the contents of the file.  (You may be spelling this `git pull`, but if so, I recommend splitting it into its two component Git commands until you really understand what each command does on its own.)

This is where things get complicated.  We must understand Git's model for commits and merges.  With this comes the role of the *index* (aka *staging area* aka *cache*), and the role of the *work-tree*, during a `git merge`.

#### How merge works

First, let's do a quick overview of commits and the merge process.  You already know<sup>1</sup> that each commit has a complete snapshot of all of your committed files, and each commit contains the hash ID(s) of its parent commit(s).  Hence if we were to draw the graph of commits after `git fetch` but before `git merge` runs, we might see this:

```
       G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD)
      /
...--F
      \
       J--K--L   <-- origin/master
```

---

<sup>1</sup>If you *don't* already know all of this, read some more about Git, e.g., the [chapter on branching in the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell).

---

What `git merge` is going to do in this case is to find the *shared* commit, the common starting point, for both your commit `I`, to which your name `master` points, and their commit `L`, to which your `origin/master` points.  Here, that's commit `F`.

Next, Git will *compare* the contents saved in commit `F` to the contents saved in your own latest commit, `I`.  That tells Git *what you changed*.  The comparison is the same as the one you can view if you run:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash of F> <hash of I>   # what we changed
```

Git will also compare the contents saved in commit `F` to the contents saved in their latest commit `L`.  That tells Git what *they* changed:

```
git diff --find-renames <hash of F> <hash of L>   # what they changed
```

Now you can see how `git merge` actually works: it combines *what you changed* with *what they changed*.  Using the combined changes, Git extracts the contents saved with the base commit—commit `F`—and applies the *combined* changes to all of the files changed in the two sets of changes.  The result, if all goes well, is the snapshot that should be committed as the merge; and Git will do that, committing the merge and adjusting your current branch:

```
       G--H--I
      /       \
...--F         M   <-- master (HEAD)
      \       /
       J--K--L   <-- origin/master
```

#### The index and the work-tree

There is a fundamental problem with files that are frozen into commits: they are (a) frozen, and (b) in a special, compressed, Git-only form.  The *frozen* part is great for source code management: these files will never change, so you can always get back your previous work, by checking out an old commit.  The special compressed Git-only form is useful for keeping your storage space under control: since Git saves every version of every file ever, if they *weren't* special and compressed, you might run out of disk space pretty fast.  But it creates a problem: *How do you get at the frozen file?  How can you change it?*

Git's answer to this is the *work-tree*.  Doing `git checkout` on some commit *expands and thaws* the files that are saved in that commit.  The thawed-out, reconstitute files go into your work-tree, where you can work with them and change them.

In other version control systems, that's the end of the story right there: you have your frozen files, which you can't change, and your unfrozen work-tree, which you can.  But Git adds this intermediate form, which Git calls the index, or the staging area, or the cache, depending on who / which part of Git is doing this calling.

Understanding the index is crucial to using Git, yet it's rarely explained very well.  People (and IDEs) try to paper over it and hide it from you.  This doesn't work, and the reason it doesn't work is important—especially in your case.

The best description I know of for the index is that it's *what will go into your next commit*.  When Git is extracting the frozen files, instead of unfreezing and de-compressing them straight into your work-tree, it first *just* unfreezes them (or more precisely, collects them into a single unified list that isn't frozen—as opposed to the more structured, frozen lists inside commits).  These now-unfrozen copies go into the index.  They are still all Git-ified, compressed and taking minimal storage.

Once a file is unfrozen into the index, only then does Git de-compress it into the work-tree format.  So it's first unfrozen (index copy), and *then* it's extracted into the work-tree.  This means the index has a copy that's ready to be frozen into the *next* commit.

If you change the file in the work-tree, you must run `git add` on that file to *copy* (and compress and Git-ify) the file so that it fits into the index.  Now the index copy matches the work-tree copy, except that the index copy is in the special Git-only form.  *Now* it's ready to go into the next commit.

This is how `git status` works: for each file, it compares the work-tree copy to the index copy, and if those are *different*, it says the file is *not staged for commit*.  It also compares the index copy—in the special Git-only format—to the `HEAD` commit copy, and if those are *different*, it says the file is *staged for commit*.  So if there are 10,000 files in the work-tree and the index and the `HEAD` commit, there are actually 30,000 copies total (10k x 3 copies).  But if only *two* of them are *different* in terms of these three copies, only two files get listed in `git status` (and the Git-ified copies are relatively tiny).

Until you run `git commit`, files that are different in the index are simply different in the index.  When you *do* run `git commit`, Git freezes the index—without even looking at the work-tree!—and makes this your new `HEAD` commit.  Your new commit now matches the index, so now all the index copies of files match their `HEAD commit copies.

(Aside: during a *conflicted* merge, the index takes on an expanded role.  Instead of just *one* copy of each file, it now holds up to *three* copies of each file.  But we're not looking at conflicted merges here, so we don't have to worry about this.)

#### The assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits

Now we can see what these two bits do.  When you run `git status`, Git normally compares the work-tree copy of every file to the index copy of the same file.  If it's different, Git says that you have a change that is *not staged for commit*.  (If the file isn't even in the index at all, Git says the file is *untracked*, and *then* the `.gitignore` file matters.  But if the file is already in the index, the file is tracked, and the `.gitignore` file does not matter.)

If you set either the assume-unchanged or skip-worktree bits, `git status` *won't* compare the work-tree version of the file to the index version.  They can be as different as you like, and `git status` will say nothing about them.

Note that `git commit` completely ignores these bits!  It simply freezes the index copy.  If the index copy matches the work-tree copy, this means you've kept the file *the same* when committing it again.  Your new commit has the same frozen copy as your previous commit.  Your index copy continues to match your `HEAD` commit copy.

The problem comes about when Git needs to *change* the file.  Let's say that you have set the skip-worktree bit (this is the one you should set, in general, as the other is meant for a different problem, although in practice either one works).  You have also modified the work-tree copy.  Running `git status` won't complain, because `git status` won't actually *compare* the work-tree copy to the index copy any more.

But now you run `git merge`, and the merge wants to take the *changes* to the file.  Git compares commit `F` to commits `I` and `L`, for instance, and finds that although you have not committed a new version of the file in `I`, *they* **did** commit a new version of the file in `L`.  So Git will take their changes, make those go into the new merge commit `M`, and then ... extract `M` into your work-tree, clobbering your copy of the file.

Clobbering your file is bad, so Git doesn't do that.  Instead, it just fails the merge.

#### What should you do about this?

Ultimately, what you must do is save your version of the file somewhere.  That could be inside Git—as a commit, for instance—or outside of Git, by copying the file outside the repository.  Then you can either merge your changes with their changes, or re-do your changes after just taking their version.

This is what `git stash` does, in fact.  It makes a commit—well, really *two* commits.  The special thing about these commits is that they are not on *any* branch.  Having made the commits, `git stash` runs `git reset --hard` to throw away your changes to the file from the index and work-tree.  You had no index changes, and even if you did the index copy is saved in the stash commits, so the `--mixed` part of the reset is safe, and your work-tree copy is saved in the stash commits, so the `--hard` part of the reset is safe.  Now that your index and work-tree are clean you can merge safely.  Then `git stash pop`—which is really `git stash apply && git stash drop`—can merge your stashed work-tree version of the file with your current version of the file, using a less-safe internal merge that works only on the work-tree copy.  The `drop` step drops the stash commits, so that they become *unreferenced*<sup>2</sup> and will eventually be removed entirely.

There are several alternatives to using `git stash` here, but none are as simple, and none are pretty.  You might as well use `git stash`.

Last, you *can* stop committing the file entirely.  Once the file is no longer in the index, it becomes *untracked* and is not in any *future* commits.  This is ultimately the best solution, in my opinion, but it has one really huge drawback: the file *has* been committed in the past.  This means that if you ever check out an *old* commit (that does have the file), the file will be in both the current commit—that old commit you've just checked out—*and* the index, and will be tracked.  When you switch away from that old commit to a new commit that *doesn't* have the file, *that* will remove the file!  This is what you mean when you say:

> I was thinking of doing `git rm --cached`, but from what I've read it seems like this will delete the file from the repo ...

Specifically, it deletes the file from the *index*, while leaving the work-tree copy alone.  This *does not delete the file from the repo*, but the repo itself is mainly composed of *commits*, and "delete from the repo" is a [nonsense phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously).  You literally *can't* delete the file from the existing commits: they are frozen forever in time.  You can only avoid putting the file into *future* commits.

This works, but leaves that trap I outlined above: going back to a historical commit restores the file to the index (because `git checkout commit` means *populate the index from a commit and use that to populate the work-tree*).  Once *in* the index, it will be in future commits.  Switching to a commit that *doesn't* have the file requires *removing* it from the index, which implies removing it from the work-tree, and now the work-tree copy is gone.

So, if you want to go this route, which is a good way to go, you should:

- stop using that file at all: rename it to `config.sample`
- switch to a new (different) file name for the actual configuration, and keep this file out of the repository entirely (store it in `$HOME/.fooconfig`, for instance)

and make that all part of one commit, after which the old configuration file is never used again.  Tell people to move their configuration to the new location before switching to the new version of the `foo` program.  Make this a major version bump, because the behavior is different.

---

<sup>2</sup>See [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

Comment: Holy guacamole, that's a thorough and well explained answer! If I had any upvotes I'd give them all. Thanks :)